# Removing duplicates with different endings in notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++

Hi how do I remove duplicates that have different endings?

I have a big list like this:

```
1.2.3.4:12345
1.2.3.4:54321
1.2.3.4:41873
1.2.3.4:48138
```

I want to remove all of them except the first one `1.2.3.4:12345`. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to remove each line where the text before the ":" appears in a previous line? So for example, if the next line were `1.2.3.5:10001`, would it be left in the list?

Comment: Yes that also works, put 1.2.3.4:12345 in and it deletes all the other lines that contain 1.2.3.4

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to remove duplicate lines for all values preceding the ":" in the file.

Search for:

```
([^:]*)(:[0-9]+)\r\n(.*)^\1:\w+(\r\n|\Z)
```

Replace with:

```
\1\2\r\n\3
```

Make sure Search Mode is "Regular Expression" and ". matches newline" is checked.

You will have to click "Replace All" until no matches are found.  Or record one iteration of this as a macro and run it as many times as necessary.